# Is dns-prefetch needed for resources that have cache policy?

Tags: browser-cache, cache-control, dns-prefetch

Is it unnecessary to add dns-prefetch for servers that return cached resources?

Does the web browser even need to resolve the domain for assets they know they have cached?

Answer (score 0):

dns-prefetch is recommended for all types of resources as its not a heavy operation.
However for cached resources dns lookups are not required and generally speaking for most of the cases the dns records are already available for the domains with cached resources.